# How to destruct in a type safe manner?

Tags: regex, kotlin

Assume you want to fetch multiple values of different types from a string by de-structuring a regex MatchResult:

```
val regex = Regex("(\\d) ([AB])")
val (num: Int, token: String) = regex.find("0 A")!!.destructured
```

The above does *not* work, as `component1() function returns String, but Int is required`.

Is there an elegant/canonical way to directly get `num` as Int, and not as String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I see is, that the parsing or transformation step is missing.

The simplest solution that comes to my mind is the following:

```
val (num : Int, token : String) = regex.find("0 A")!!.destructured.let { 
    (s, s2) -> s.toInt() to s2
}
```

But elegant/canonical? I leave that up to you.

I don't know of any other built-in feature that does an automatic transformation ;-)

Comment: One part of my question(s) today ... is to fathom "option space" in Kotlin ;-) your answer definitely helps.